# Sorting an array by values, then by keys preserving values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

This is my array:

```
   [2] => Array
            (
                [2012-08-13 10:56:37] => Array
                    (
                        [5] => 5.4E-7
                    )

                [2012-08-13 10:57:36] => Array
                    (
                        [4] => 2.1E-7
                    )

                [2012-08-13 10:54:00] => Array
                    (
                        [6] => 0
                    )

                [2012-08-13 10:53:17] => Array
                    (
                        [3] => 0
                    )

                [2012-08-13 10:54:42] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                    )

            )
```

Dates, inside keys and values.
This is what I want, order by values inside the keys of the dates, then order by dates.

It is already ordered by values as you can see - desc, but if I sort the dates I lost the desc sort made for the values, I'd like newer dates first (desc) but if a value is higher inside the array then ignore a newer date during the sort.

Comment: foreach, (or any loop), recursion... you can do it in multiple ways... but i think the way you store date will make it easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

use `ksort();` it sort an array by key.

**Example:**

```
$test =  Array
         (
                [2012-08-13 10:56:37] => Array
                    (
                        [5] => 5.4E-7
                    )

                [2012-08-13 10:57:36] => Array
                    (
                        [4] => 2.1E-7
                    )
          )

ksort($test);
foreach ($test as $key => $val) {
    echo "$key = $val\n";
}
```